# How to add two kanban views for same model, even though there are two different actions but still it shows same view

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to add new **kanban** view for `hr.employee` model , i give the different actions for two kanban view , but it's showing same views for two kanban views.How can i add two different kanban view for same model.

Comment: please answer , help me

Comment: you make one more action for kanban view.

Comment: i make two different actions , but not working

Comment: it's working fine for kanban view , but still problem with tree view, same tree views showing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49630050/9020824

Answer (score 0):

Bind your action with your custom view.

```
<record id="action_cancel_holidays_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
        <field name="sequence" eval="2"/>
        <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="cancel_holiday_tree"/>
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="open_cancel_holidays"/>
</record>
```

act_window_id :- your action id
view_id :- view id
This is an example.

Comment: raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)

Comment: prashant replace view_id, dont use mine, thats an example

Comment: yah, i replace dwith my id

Comment: then update question with your code, then only we can help you

Comment: <record id="action_view_categ_birthday_kanban" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="sequence" eval="2"/>
            <field name="name">Today Birthday's</field>
            <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="domain">[('birthday','like',context_today().strftime("%____%-%m-%d"))]</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,form,tree</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_categ_birthday_kanban"/>
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="open_view_categ_birthday"/>
              </record>

Comment: you are trying to define view id in action itself, anyway use the module_name.view_id.

Comment: and you combined two models here, use my code , this is not for defining action, but bind a new view with an action.

Comment: just use my answer and you only need to replace view id and act_window id

Comment: still showing error , please make changes my code and post, thanks advance

Comment: my main intension is i have to make separate kanban view for today birthdays employees. I take the new menu item for the hr.employee but it change the default exist kanban view for employees menu

Comment: please help me , in my custom module my kanban view showing same as depend module. how to get both different view , i tried with view_id ref and act_window_id ref ,but not working fine